# Getting Modernizr.mq working in IE 8

Tags: modernizr

I'm using `Modernizr.mq`(http://modernizr.com/docs/#mq) to run checks in my JS, and I was under the impression that the [**Respond**](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) polyfill would make `Modernizr.mq` work in IE 8 as IE 8 does not support media queries but this isn't the case, see this test page in IE 8: http://goo.gl/ND9sA, the bg should be orange according to this:

```
if (Modernizr.mq('screen and (min-width: 650px)')) {
     $('body').css('background', 'orange');
}
```

So does **Respond** only work for media queries specified within CSS and not JS? I thought `Modernizr.mq` uses [**matchMedia**](http://caniuse.com/matchmedia) and **Respond** includes the **matchMedia** [polyfill](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) but still doesn't work.

So how do you get `Modernizr.mq` working for IE 8 or can't you?

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr doesn't change the values of its tests if you load polyfills, so if the browser doesn't support media queries, `Modernizr.mq()` will return `false`, and adding the Respondjs polyfill won't change that.

Sorry about that.

Having said that, if you've got the polyfill loaded, then you're already doing all you can to support old browsers (Respondjs supports IE6/7/8), so there's not a huge amount more you can achieve with the Modernizr flag. , You theoretically shouldn't need to use the Modernizr test with the polyfill in place, as all browsers should support the feature anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah I **was** only using **Respond** for old IE (8 & below) thinking it would fix up media query support in my JS via `Modernizr.mq` but that's pointless like you say so I'm back to checking the viewport width like this: `document.body.clientWidth`. For my CSS I use Sass so I can use this great technique for old IE media query support: http://jakearchibald.github.com/sass-ie/.